# Unable to install coala-bears cloned from the repository with pip install

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, coala, coala-bears

I created two repositories local one coala & coala-bears after cloning from 
* git@github.com:coala/coala.git
* git@github.com:coala/coala-bears.git

cd into coala-bears folder on windows 7 64 bit 
issued "command pip install ."
Got a para of errors , any help is appreciated , tried to install libxml binaries from unofficial repos for Win 64 bit amd arch

Here are installation log errors :

```
9999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: coala-utils~=0.6.2 in c:\program files\python36\l
ib\site-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev9
9999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: unidiff~=0.5.2 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999
999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: PyPrint~=0.2.6 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999
999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=17.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib
\site-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev999
99999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs~=1.4 in c:\program files\python36\lib\sit
e-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev9999999
9999999)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore>=1.17.1 in c:\program files\python36\li
b\site-packages (from bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-
packages (from bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: GitPython>=1.0.1 in c:\program files\python36\lib
\site-packages (from bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: polib>=1.0.8 in c:\program files\python36\lib\sit
e-packages (from dennis~=0.8->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt>=0.6.1 in c:\program files\python36\lib\si
te-packages (from html-linter~=0.3.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: template-remover in c:\program files\python36\lib
\site-packages (from html-linter~=0.3.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\program files\pytho
n36\lib\site-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999
)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\program files\python36\lib\sit
e-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\program files\python36\lib
\site-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-pack
ages (from proselint~=0.7.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: snowballstemmer in c:\program files\python36\lib\
site-packages (from pydocstyle~=2.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid>=1.5.1 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from pylint~=1.6->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-pack
ages (from pylint~=1.6->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\program f
iles\python36\lib\site-packages (from pylint~=1.6->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev999999
99999999)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-pa
ckages (from pyroma~=2.2.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: mando<0.4,>=0.3 in c:\program files\python36\lib\
site-packages (from radon==1.4.0->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=2.3.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from vim-vint~=0.3.12->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Collecting ansicolor~=0.2.4 (from vim-vint~=0.3.12->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999
999999999)
  Using cached ansicolor-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in c:\program files\python36\lib\s
ite-packages (from requests~=2.12->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears=
=0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files\python36\l
ib\site-packages (from requests~=2.12->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-be
ars==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in c:\program files\python3
6\lib\site-packages (from requests~=2.12->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala
-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: sarge~=0.1.4 in c:\program files\python36\lib\sit
e-packages (from dependency-management~=0.4.0->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->
coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-p
ackages (from packaging~=16.8->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bears==0.1
2.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor~=1.1.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib
\site-packages (from PyPrint~=0.2.6->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170604215434->coala-bear
s==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\python36\l
ib\site-packages (from stevedore>=1.17.1->bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99
999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: gitdb2>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib\si
te-packages (from GitPython>=1.0.1->bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999
999999)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-p
ackages (from traitlets>=4.1->nbformat~=4.1->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev999999999999
99)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packa
ges (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint~=1.6->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev99999999999999)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy in c:\program files\python36\li
b\site-packages (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint~=1.6->coala-bears==0.12.0.dev999999
99999999)
Requirement already satisfied: smmap2>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib\si
te-packages (from gitdb2>=2.0.0->GitPython>=1.0.1->bandit~=1.2->coala-bears==0.1
2.0.dev99999999999999)
Building wheels for collected packages: coala-bears, lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for coala-bears ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\mindwarrior\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\4a\7f
\b1\975dc7655c8c1f955e9c35e2a3cbf33faedc19f8729ab6dae1
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "imp
ort setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MINDWA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pi
p-build-00n_zh3t\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);co
de=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec')
)" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptsregsflpip-wheel- --p
ython-tag cp36:
  Building lxml version 3.6.0.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r
\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes

  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\html
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\iso
schematron
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml
  copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\include
s
  copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\incl
udes
  copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\inclu
des
  copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes

  copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\inclu
des
  copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\include
s
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\include
s
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includ
es
  copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includ
es
  copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\includes
  copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\include
s
  copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\inclu
des
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.w
in-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-a
md64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-a
md64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematr
on-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract
_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-sche
matron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_inc
lude.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schemat
ron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematr
on_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-s
chematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematr
on_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resource
s\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for
_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schem
atron-xslt1
  copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\src\lxml
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c
 /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes "-Ic:\program files\python
36\include" "-Ic:\program files\python36\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include
\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\includ
e\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits
\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Releas
e\src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
  lxml.etree.c
  src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include fil
e: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  creating Users
  creating Users\MINDWA~1
  creating Users\MINDWA~1\AppData
  creating Users\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local
  creating Users\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c
 /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x8
6)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1
\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo
ws Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /TcC:\Users\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit
ov510k8m.c /FoUsers\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitov510k8m.obj
  xmlXPathInitov510k8m.c
  C:\Users\MINDWA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitov510k8m.c(1): fatal error C1
083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
  ******************************************************************************
***
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 install
ed?
  ******************************************************************************
***
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN
\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Successfully built coala-bears
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: coala, apertium-lint, lxml, memento-client, pydoc
style, rstcheck, ansicolor, vim-vint, coala-bears
  Found existing installation: coala 0.11.0
    Uninstalling coala-0.11.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\li
b\\site-packages\\coala-0.11.0.dist-info\\description.rst' -> 'C:\\Users\\MINDWA
~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-0iatizw2-uninstall\\program files\\python36\\lib\\
site-packages\\coala-0.11.0.dist-info\\description.rst'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
5, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 77
8, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", l
ine 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\shutil.py", line 553, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\li
b\\site-packages\\coala-0.11.0.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

Comment: Either use an elevated shell or a virtual environment, so the output won't be cluttered with unrelated permission errors. Also, the problem is with installing the lxml dependency, so try installing lxml on its own, and update your question with the result.

Comment: I am running by default using CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER as administrator, even have it installed , issue is with libxml2

Comment: Yes @eryksun , i have updated pip to latest version running 9.0.1

Comment: Have you installed lxml on its own via `pip install lxml`?

Comment: yes, I have tried that, got this message when issue pip install lxml "Collecting lxml
 Using cached lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
installing collected packages: lxml
successfully installed lxml-3.8.0"

Comment: I took a look at the latest beta release on PyPI (0.12.0.dev20170615074004), it depends on exactly lxml 3.6.0, which is an old version that doesn't have wheels for Python 3.6 on PyPI. You should open an issue for this on the coala-bears issue tracker. It's unreasonable to expect Windows users to build lxml from source.